# Applying the Date format to the Parsed Date in D3 V3.5

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to coding and I wanted to get some kind of confirmation on how to *format dates* once I parsed them in *D3 API 3.5*. I'm sorry if I don't have the wording correctly.

I keep getting errors every time I try to type out anything like `formatDate(parseDate(d.date))`. The reason why you see the `d.date` in both the `deathdata` and `daydata` is because both of the data sets contain the string `"%d-%b"`, for example `"1-Sep"`. I don't have a lot of background but I hope this code makes some sense.

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b").parse; //formats and parses incoming date
var formatDate = d3.time.format("%b-%d"); //formats the outgoing date (supposedly)
    daydata.forEach(function(d){
         d.date = parseDate(d.date)
         return formatDate(parseDate(d.date));
         d.deaths = +d.deaths;
    });
    deathdata.forEach(function(d){
         d.date = parseDate(d.date);
         d.age = +d.age
         d.gender = +d.gender
         d.x = +d.x
         d.y = +d.y
    });
```

I want to see if I can apply my `formatDate` to the *parsed time* that I have described below that.

Comment: Your code works, there is no error: https://jsfiddle.net/L90zauwp/1/. What's exactly your question? By the way, `return` inside a `forEach` won't do anything.

Comment: So the code works to parse the Time but if I wanted to say retrieve the time, it will spit out the the UTC (day, month, year, weekday, etc). I put a format to produce shortened month and day, but I'm having trouble applying that format. Is there anyway I can do this? I can send the full code if it helps

Comment: I guess you can ignore the return line. I just wanted to test it out from other users, I get an error "t-slice is not a function"

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking, sorry. Please, take your time and edit your question, **clearly** stating what's your problem and your desired outcome. I hope someone else can help you.

Comment: in your code, parseDate and formatDate are the inverse of each other. applying both  will just yield the original input. How about showing us the content of your arrays?

Comment: I thought I did. I did say to apply the formatted date, "abbreviated month and day" to the parsed date. The original data was "day and abbreviated month" if that is something that was not clear from before, but I am trying to change it to the formatted date. I found that this is the only way I can parse the date using d3 version 3.5. Thanks for trying anyway.

Comment: This is a sample of what my data is from. Its a csv file                                                             
date,deaths
19-Aug,1
20-Aug,1
21-Aug,1
22-Aug,0
23-Aug,1
24-Aug,1
25-Aug,0
26-Aug,1
27-Aug,1
28-Aug,1
29-Aug,1
30-Aug,8
31-Aug,56
1-Sep,143
2-Sep,116

Comment: Ouch, I misread the format :/